# How to create a template literal type from object to have keys=values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object

```
{
  foo: "bar",
  a: "b",
  roses: "red",
}
```

I would like to create a template literal which would give me the following possibilities:

```
"foo=bar" | "a=b" | "roses=red"
```

So basically, key=value

What I've done so far is:

```
type Foo = `${keyof typeof obj}=${typeof obj[keyof typeof obj]}`;
```

But this give me every possible combination:

```
"foo=bar" | "foo=b" | "foo=red" | "a=bar" | ...
```

I feel I need to use a generic but I'm not able to make it work

Comment: You can visit this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nKBeKBvAsAKCrBAuKAIgCMBDAJ0Kx1IJKuynLgGcIW7yIATBgXyxYAxnAB2LYFDLkC8RCgyM5daYQA01KLSLF1m5mw5EuvDZj5A). I don't know if it can meet your requirements.

Comment: COnsider [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1PpYW) approach. If it works I will provide an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a self-indexing [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
const obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  a: "b",
  roses: "red",
} as const;

type Foo = {
    [K in keyof typeof obj]: `${K}=${typeof obj[K]}`
}[keyof typeof obj];
```

This evaluates to:

```
type Foo = "foo=bar" | "a=b" | "roses=red"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAzEIAXDAETwCGATiQDTYznFm32UgQCmETlHAJiwC+DCDFCQoAbkyYoATwAOHGADECqDPRwBtANIwAlmBgBrDnJC4Y8pZbhIAusQAGAEnS7BKdzY52EiHoOgs6YgtpmFla+-o6SQA)